# How to get different shades of colors for a single color?

Tags: d3.js

How can I get different shades of color for single color by using d3.js?

For example:

`colorScale('myId') => 'red'` and `colorScale(red)(10)` => `dark red` & `colorScale(red)(1)` => `light red`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given your description of the desired outcome, I highly doubt that you want *shades*: technically speaking, shades are mixtures of a given colour with **black**, reducing its lightness.

So, assuming that you really want *shades*, the task can be done with a simple linear scale going from `"red"` to `"black"` and using `[0, 40]` as the domain (here using D3 v5.8 new constructor):

```
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([0,40], ["red", "black"])
```

You can also set a interpolator if you want to change some values, as the gamma:

```
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([0,40], ["red", "black"])
    .interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb.gamma(1.9));
```

Here is the demo:

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([0, 40], ["red", "black"])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb.gamma(1.9));
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(41))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

By using more different values in the domain we can create a gradient with the shades (this is just a demo, don't append 500 divs for creating a gradient!):

```js
const scale = d3.scaleLinear([0, 500], ["red", "black"])
  .interpolate(d3.interpolateRgb.gamma(1.9));
d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(d3.range(501))
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .style("background-color", d => scale(d))
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `d3.rgb.brighter(k)` or `d3.rgb.darker(k)` from [d3 documentation](https://devdocs.io/d3~5/d3-color#color).

Like this: `let red = d3.rgb("red")`, which gives red the rgb value of d3 representation of red (r=255). Then, `red.darker(0.5)` give a darker red (r=213):

```js
let red = d3.rgb("red");
let darker = red.darker(0.5);
console.log(darker.toString())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Note: the `brighter` and `darker` can be applied to other type of color (hsl, rgba,...)

Comment: I created a running demo, which is always good, I hope you don't mind.

Answer (score 0):

Top comment works perfect, but if anybody is using d3 v3 then this would work as well.

```
var colors = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 3]).range(["yellow", "red"]);
colors(0); // Yellow
colors(3); // Red
```